# Invite friends popup is struggling, if the user is not logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, invite

I have created an invite friends code, which is properly working if an FB user is logged in.

If I remember correctly, it also worked, when there were no active fb users, in this case it simply shown a fb login page and then it went to an invitation.

Currently the 'invite facebook friends' link is really struggling, if there aren't any active facebook users.

```
    FB.ui({
                    appId:  '"' + appId + '"',
                    method: 'apprequests',
                    display: 'iframe',
                    message: '"' + message + '"',
                    title: 'Send your friends an application request'
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (response && response.request_ids) {
                        FB.api(response.request_ids, 'delete');
                    }
                });
```

[image]

Did I do something wrong, or is this a bug in the Facebook invitation?

Comment: Anybody? It's a really annoying problem, also it's impossible to rais e a ticket on the bug tracker site  (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs ) It makes same thing, jus loading while sending, I waited twenty minutes , but nothing happened.

Comment: Why are you firing the dialog for a user if you're not sure they're logged in?

Comment: Try to figure it out on a different way: Why do you like a page , if anybody isn't logged in to a facebook?! 

I think it's trivial, if I want to invite my facebook friends , or like  a page, or any other fb-connected thing , then it needs to show a  login screen if there aren't any live fb session.

Comment: I mean, your app should already know if the user is logged in - so you could omit that dialog when the user isn't logged in

Comment: Yes , I know that , but I'd like to show the invite friends button /dialog to everybody .  I'm not sure, you understood my problem very well. The perfect answer should be that if it's not there yet:  okey this feature (login screen on calls,  if the user is not logged in ) is not implemented in the facebook api yet. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, I got an answer on the Facebook bug site. However, it should help anybody , who has a  lack of FB api knowledge . The documentation  didn't show this example:
If there aren't any active fb session , it just open a login screen. 
Finally I just realised what happened:

**It doesn't show a  login screen , if you use an IFRAME**.

Do not use that!!

Thank you for Noorin Ladhani.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('send-to-many').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Visit my page'
  }, Log.info.bind('send-to-many callback'));
}
</script>
```